# How to Build IM like eBuddy or Pidgin

Tags: instant, messenger

I've read some questions and answers about IM, etc. But I still don't understand how to **combine** Yahoo messenger, Google Talk, MSN and even Facebook chat so we can see the buddy list, status, etc from one of those IM (like in Ebuddy)...
Help please... I'm working on my final project....

THANK YOU :D

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please narrow it to something specific and clear. Maybe you could actually TRY to use pidgin with multiple accounts together and see how it works on the user interface.

Comment: I mean, how to make an IM like Pidgin,Ebuddy ? and how can I access this facebook chat API? [Facebook Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)

Answer (score 2):

You could get your hand on the source code of pidgin and learn. It also contains a plugin to connect to Facebook's chat. That's the most straight and useful way.